# How get the selected value in DropDownList with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DropDownList which I want to get what is selected with jquery

I had it in the following way:

```
$('#ddlTerminal').change(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
GetTerminal();
});

$('#ddlTerminal').blur(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
GetTerminal();
});
```

I was investigating a little but I do not quite clear and try with the following:

```
$('#ddlTerminal option:selected').change(function (e) {
GetTerminal();
alert(this.value);
});
```

Since once it identifies, that is selected in my DropDownList I want to modify the information that appears in a window.
I hope you can give me information, or some idea that might be useful since I'm starting with jquery.
I am working with C # - Jquery

Comment: I'm sure you'd get more help if you try to improve a description and question.

Answer (score 0):

Its so simple

```
  $('#ddlTerminal').change(function (e) {
 alert($(this).val()); /*
assuming ddlTerminal is select tag */ 
 e.preventDefault(); 

 GetTerminal(); // don't know whats this.
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Taufeek,
With this must appear an alert of what I am selecting in my ddlterminal is correct, since it does not appear to me.

I must have something more or only this that you indicate me?

Greetings.

Comment: Can I see your html? @Molitaa

Comment: Is #ddlTerminal is select tag?

Comment: $('#ddlTerminal').change(function (e) { alert($(this).val()); }); try this code and make sure only this change event is there for ddlTerminal select tag.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not get the alert to appear, I have added the jquery in the DropDownList form. I have reviewed the conola of my browser and I do not frame error, what can be happening?

Comment: Some idea of why the alert can not appear to me,

I have the function of the following way: $(function () {
    $('#ddlTerminal').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});


I have added jquery to my form
I do not know if I need to add any more.

Comment: Well, try $(document).ready(function () { $(document).on('change','#ddlTerminal', function () { alert($(this).val()); }); }); And let me see the source code.

Comment: And also look at your browsers console, is there something error?

Comment: The console does not display error.
  How can you see the code, in images?

I have alertprefa.js there I only have the function of ddlterminal and this is added to my screen princiapl:
<Script src = "Scripts / alertprefa.js" type = "text / javascript"> </ script>

Comment: Thanks for the help, what was missing was to place an identifier in the DropDownList

Thanks.